# Office Add-in that supports SSO (and Word Online?)

Tags: office-js

Just finished the proof of concept for an Office Add-in idea I have and want to implement user sign-in.
I want users to be able to login but also bundle them if they are part of an organization. (My plan is it to use their domain name for that.)

Client side I'm using Angular 5 and my plan is it to use Node.js server side. Now I found this source:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO

In the prerequisites there is mention of Office 2016. No Word Online though.
Am I to understand that this example is not ment for Word Online?

I also had a look at Auth0 but that uses something called Guard (their own login screen) which uses a pop-up login for authentication.
Does anyone use that? I ask this because I've read that an Office Add-in doesn't allow to use popup's.

All ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `IdentityAPI` and [`getAccessTokenAsync()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync) method is supported by Word Online and Word 2016 for both Windows and Mac.

You can find the complete list of supported platforms in the [IdentityAPI Requirement Sets](http://%20https//dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/identity-api-requirement-sets) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

SSO for Office Add-ins is still in preview, but the preview version should support Office Online. The particular sample that you linked to has only been tested on desktop Office.

To work with Auth0, we recommend that you use the Dialog API in office.js. See this sample for details: [Office-Add-in-Auth0](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Auth0)

If you haven't already, please read:

[Authorize external services in Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins)

[Enable SSO for Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins)